# Issue while using orderby in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view of several records fetched from my database.I implemented pagination for the records to display 3 records per page and it is working fine. Now I wish to provide a drop down to toggle between Ascending and Descending order of the records. The default view is in ascending order. Now the problem is when I click descending option from the drop down the records are changing to descending order, but it takes me to the first page.

I need to stay on the same page when I change the order of the records. Is there any possible way to achieve this using sessions. Because I wish to solve this problem without using ajax. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Here's my controller:**

```
<?php 

class Datalist extends CI_Controller{
public function __Construct(){
parent::__Construct();
$this->load->model('myapp/list_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->library('pagination');
}

public function index(){

if(!isset($_SESSION["name"])){
 redirect("myapp/login");
}

$config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/myapp/datalist/index"."/";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->list_model->get_count();
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config["num_links"] = 2;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

if($this->input->post('order')){
 $_SESSION['order'] = $this->input->post('order');
}

if(isset($_SESSION['order'])){
 $order = $_SESSION['order'];
}else{
 $order = "ASC";
}

$limit = 3;

$offset = ($this->uri->segment(4))?$this->uri->segment(4):0;

$data['result'] = $this->list_model->get_list($offset,$limit,$order);

$data['games'] = $this->list_model->get_games();
$data['map'] = $this->list_model->get_map();

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$this->load->view('myapp/list_view,$data);

 }

}
 ?>
```

**Here's my Model**

```
 class List_model extends CI_Model{

 public function __Construct(){
  $this->load->database();
}

public function get_list($offset, $limit, $order){

$offset = $offset-1;

if($offset<0){
  $offset = 0;
}

$from = $offset * $limit;

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT userData.Id,
                  userData.FirstName,
                  userData.LastName,
                  genderList.name,
                  userData.Email,
                  userData.Dob,
                  country.countryName,
                  state.stateName,
                  city.cityName,
                  userData.Pincode 
                  FROM userData 
                  LEFT JOIN country
                  ON userData.Country = country.countryId
                  LEFT JOIN state
                  ON userData.State = state.stateId 
                  LEFT JOIN city
                  ON userData.City = city.cityId
                  LEFT JOIN genderList
                  ON userData.Gender = genderList.genderId
                  ORDER BY userData.FirstName $order
                  LIMIT $limit OFFSET $from ");

return $query->result();
}

public function get_games(){
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from games");
  return $query->result_array();
}
public function get_map(){
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from mapGame");
  return $query->result_array();
}
public function get_count(){
  return $this->db->count_all("userData");
}
}
?>
```

**My View**

```
<div class = "list">
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Interest</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Pincode</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <?php foreach($result as $data): ?> 
       <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->FirstName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->LastName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->Email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->Dob; ?></td>
        <td><?php 
          foreach($map as $mapping):
            if($data->Id == $mapping["userId"]){
              foreach($games as $name):
            if($mapping["GameId"] == $name["gameId"]){
              echo $name["name"]."<br>";
            }
              endforeach;
            }
          endforeach;
        ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $data->countryName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->stateName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->cityName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->Pincode; ?></td></tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<div align="center" style="margin-top:10px;background-color: #F1F8E0">
<?php echo $links; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "order">
  <?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION["order"])){
    if($_SESSION['order'] == 'ASC'){
     $order = 'ASC';
    }else{
     $order = 'DESC';
    }
  }else{
   $order = 'ASC';
  }
  echo form_open('myapp/datalist/index');
  echo form_label('Order');
  echo form_dropdown('order',array('ASC'=>'Ascending', 
   'DESC'=>'Descending'),$order,array('onclick'=>'this.form.submit()'));
  echo form_close();
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, why do you want to stay on the same page if I may ask? The records will be different no doubt. Just curious. Otherwise I'd suggest saving the current page in a session var and just redirecting to that page after changing the order. You already use session vars for order, so this a good potential for a self-answer! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alex. This is a task given by my mentor. I was asked to add a search filter and order option for these records. I have to maintain all the changes while staying on the same page itself. Only after reading your comment I realized that there is no point in staying on the same page. Eventually I will try using sessions and complete it. After that I will clarify it with my mentor. @Alex :)